# Looking for a proper term for "rail freight surcharge"

Tags: word-request, translation

From a text I'm translating:

> The current export freight rate that covers a range of shipments, including mineral fertilizer shipments, includes a 13.4 % **surcharge**.

[Russian Railways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Railways) officially charge the same rate as they charged back in the beginning of 2014. However, in late 2014 they [increased](https://www.vedomosti.ru/business/articles/2016/06/03/643466-rzhd-ne-hochet-otkazivatsya-134-noi-nadbavki-eksport-nefti) this rate "temporarily" by 13.4% for a range of goods, to mitigate the losses caused by the fall of the ruble.

In Russian the word for this increase is "надбавка" ("an add-on", probably, when rendered literally). The Multitran dictionary offers a bevy of possible translations: [надбавка](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%ED%E0%E4%E1%E0%E2%EA%E0).

Is **surcharge** a good option here? If not, what could be a better one?

Comment: You could also call it a **levy**. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22charged%20a%20levy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common term for this is **surcharge**.  This is most often a *temporary* charge added to cover unexpected costs, such as a change in fuel prices.  Sometimes these charges are "rolled back", but [frequently not](http://www.alternet.org/story/153769/the_5_most_outrageous_examples_of_hidden_charges_companies_pass_off_on_consumers_--_and_how_to_fight_back).

If it is official government action, it might be instead called a **"(something) fee"**.  For example the [TSA added a "security fee" after the attacks of 2001/9/11](https://www.tsa.gov/for-industry/security-fees) which, while supposedly "temporary" will probably never be rolled back.